# Web application for efficient placement of blocks

Tags: 2d, javascript, json, html, css

Task: to develop a function that efficiently places rectangular blocks in
rectangular 2D container. The location of the blocks in the container should be
as dense as possible in order to rationally use the space of the container.

I am almost done but I have some problems with my code: items
overlap each other

Here is my code, but I don't want use some libraries:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Block Placement Algorithm</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    .block {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="container"></div>

  <script>
 function checkOverlap(newBlock, existingBlocks) {
  for (const block of existingBlocks) {
    if (
      newBlock.right >= block.left - blockMargin &&
      newBlock.left <= block.right + blockMargin &&
      newBlock.bottom >= block.top - blockMargin &&
      newBlock.top <= block.bottom + blockMargin
    ) {
      return true; // Якщо є перекриття з існуючим блоком
    }
  }
  return false; // Якщо немає перекриття з існуючими блоками
}

    function calculateBlockArea(blockCoordinates) {
      let totalBlockArea = 0;

      for (const block of blockCoordinates) {
        totalBlockArea += block.width * block.height;
      }

      return totalBlockArea;
    }

    // Generate block coordinates
    const blockCoordinates = [];
    const containerWidth = 500;
    const containerHeight = 500;
    const maxAttempts = 100;
    const blockMargin = 0; 

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 50;
      const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 50;

      let newBlock;
      let attempts = 0;
      do {
        newBlock = {
          top: Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerHeight - height)),
          left: Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerWidth - width)),
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          initialOrder: i + 1,
          width: width,
          height: height
        };

        newBlock.right = newBlock.left + width;
        newBlock.bottom = newBlock.top + height;

        attempts++;
      } while (checkOverlap(newBlock, blockCoordinates) && attempts < maxAttempts);

      blockCoordinates.push(newBlock);
    }

    // Sort blocks by initialOrder
    blockCoordinates.sort((a, b) => a.initialOrder - b.initialOrder);

    // Render blocks on the page
    const container = document.getElementById('container');

    let currentTop = 0;
    let currentLeft = 0;

    blockCoordinates.forEach(block => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'block';
      div.style.width = block.width + 'px';
      div.style.height = block.height + 'px';

      // Set position based on the order with margin
      div.style.top = currentTop + 'px';
      div.style.left = currentLeft + 'px';
      div.textContent = block.initialOrder;

      const randomColor = "#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
      div.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;

      container.appendChild(div);

      currentLeft += block.width + blockMargin; 
      if (currentLeft + block.width > containerWidth) {
        currentTop += block.height + blockMargin; 
        currentLeft = 0; 
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement:

```js
if (currentLeft + block.width > containerWidth) {
  currentTop += block.height + blockMargin; 
  currentLeft = 0; 
}
```

you're setting the value of `currentTop` based on height of the current block that's causing the wrap.

Instead you need to know the max height of the first row's blocks for the x-axis range that the new block is covering. This pen works for the second row of blocks, but it needs to be further edited so that the 3rd+ row will work - Because the heights of the second row are all unique it isn't particularly straightforward to calculate the height of the third row.

https://codepen.io/TerabyteTiger/pen/eYXeObp?editors=1011

A lot of what I did could probably be abstracted out into functions, but I wanted to leave it all inline so that it's easier for you to review what I'm doing where. Good luck!